# How do you use a link_to helper in a YML file that is being sanitized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, link-to, sanitize

I have this key in my `locales.yml` file that uses a `link_to` helper.

```
payment_types:
   credit_card: "Requires bank authorization. <%= link_to 'Tutorial', 'www.linktotutorial.com', target: '_blank' %>"
```

Previously we used an a tag with the href inside along with sanitize, like so:

```
sanitize(t("payment_types.#{payment_type}"),
                tags: %w(a), attributes: %w(target href)), payment_type
```

But I have to refactor it to use the `link_to` helper.

The problem is that sanitize is filtering the `erb` tag alltogether (nothing appears past "Requires bank authorization"), and I can't find a way to allow the `erb` tag and render the `link_to` properly.
Getting rid of sanitize in the other hand, renders the string with the `erb` tags included.

Are `erb` tags even allowed in yml files?

Answer (score 1):

To parse that ERB tag you can create something like locales.yml.erb
But again there will be too much of hassle to check if Rails is internally parsing ERB yml or not.
And even if it is parsing then will link_to helper will be available or not.

---

Instead I would suggest a simple way:

```
# locales.yml
payment_types:
   credit_card_html: "Requires bank authorization. %{titorial_link}"
```

```
# Usage in views
= t("payment_types.#{payment_type}_html", tutorial_link: link_to('Tutorial', 'www.linktotutorial.com', target: '_blank'))
```

Please note `_html` suffix. It is for HTML safe translations.
Read more about HTML safe translations [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations)